# Displaying images in a div on input type file on change in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, onchange

Displaying images in a div on input type file on select or change in react.

```
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
<input type="file" ></input>
```

How to display upto 10 images?

Comment: I don't think you can display images inside a `<textarea>`.

Comment: Or else how to display those images in a <div /> in react?

Comment: You can use the input's `.files` and turn them into `<img>`s using basic React list rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and uploud how much files or images you want. Have a good work ! :)

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
```